# How to do use max in where clause in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT NAME, date, price 
    FROM purchase 
    WHERE Max(date) < '$lastweek' 
       AND NAME = '$customer' 
       GROUP BY NAME;
```

How will the query find the most recent date and check that date with the given date?

Comment: Don't do this `'$variable'` instead `"$variable2"`

Comment: Sir i know but my question is about Max(date) in where clause.

Comment: `Select namen date, (SELECT Max(date) from purchase AS MaxDate) where MaxDate` and so on and so forth..

Comment: It's not really clear what your query is supposed to return. Can you add the desired output for a customer who has made a purchase in the last week and for a customer who has not made a purchase in the last week but has made more than one purchase in the past?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT NAME, date, price 
    FROM purchase 
    WHERE (SELECT Max(date) FROM purchase) < '$lastweek' 
       AND NAME = '$customer' 
       GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: select name,date,price from purchase where (select Max(date) from purchase where name='$customer' ) < '$lastweek' group by name;

is that OK?

Comment: SELECT name,date,price FROM purchase WHERE (SELECT MAX(date) FROM purchase WHERE name='$customer') < '$lastweek' AND name='$customer' GROUP BY name;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `SELECT MAX(date)`from purchase as subquery ?

```
SELECT NAME, date, price 
    FROM purchase 
    WHERE (SELECT Max(date)) < $lastweek
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT name, MAX(date) as latest_date, price 
FROM purchase 
WHERE name= '$customer' 
GROUP BY name HAVING latest_date = '$date';
```